# Could not load package intervention/image in http://packagist.org

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I don't know why, but I have this error when I try to install intervention/image in Laravel:

[RuntimeException] Could not load package intervention/image in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint 4.x.x: Invalid version string "4.x.x"

Comment: I don't know why someone could downvote your question. You've just saved me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved that by updating composer itself first.

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: Updating composer fixes the error. I have no clue why this answer was down voted.